# Why does D3 not insert elements inside the selected element, when using data().enter()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm doing a bit of messing around with D3 (v7) and noticed something odd while working with inserting elements inside another element.

Here is what's happening:
Inside the body tag, I have a single div element

> ```
> <div id='graph'></div>
> ```

In my JS, which is called upon loading the body, I have three commands:

> ```
> // declare a sample array
> var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
>
> // 1) Insert the contents of 'dataset' in a <p> inside #graph
> d3.select("#graph").insert('p').text(dataset)
>
> // 2) Insert a <div> with the class 'block' inside #graph
> d3.select("#graph")
> .insert("div")
> .attr("class", "block")
>
> // 3) Insert one <div> per each element inside 'dataset' with the class 'block' inside #graph
> d3.select("#graph")
>     .data(dataset)
>     .enter()
>     .insert("div")
>     .attr("class", "block")
> ```

The way I understand it, each of the three sentences above should create elements inside #graph. However, for some reason, the third command is inserting the 4 div.block outside the body element, like so:

> ```
> <body>
>     <div id="graph">
>         <p>5,10,15,20,25</p>
>         <div class="block"></div>
>     </div>
> </body> 
> <div class="block"></div>
> <div class="block"></div>
> <div class="block"></div>
> <div class="block"></div>
> ```

I'm not sure why the divs in the third sentence are being appended after  instead of inside  #graph even though I'm doing `d3.select("#graph")` at the beginning of the command.
I think I might be missing another command after `.data().enter()`

Why are the divs being inserted after ?
and
How can I make it so that these divs are created inside #graph instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify to what you are appending things: you need to select the container and then select the elements you wish to add/remove/update:

```
d3.select("#graph")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .insert("div")
    .attr("class", "block")
```

Without specifying a container, you are using the document as the parent, while the first datum will be bound to the selected div (#graph) the rest of the data will be bound to new divs appended to the document (*not the body*), hence why they appear where the do.

The snippet below adopts your code with that  change (and some text to indicate whether the div is updated or entered):

```js
// declare a sample array
var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

// 1) Insert the contents of 'dataset' in a <p> inside #graph
d3.select("#graph").insert('p').text(dataset)

// 2) Insert a <div> with the class 'block' inside #graph
d3.select("#graph")
.insert("div")
.attr("class", "block")

// 3) Insert one <div> per each element inside 'dataset' with the class 'block' inside #graph
var selection = d3.select("#graph")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset);
    
selection.enter().insert("div")
    .attr("class", "block")
    .text(d=>"entered:" + d); 
    
selection.text(d=>"updated:" + d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='graph'></div>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I couldn't understand why the code I found always selected body then an element. Thanks!